# Can RFID work through metal?

Tags: rfid

Basically, is there any way to fully encapsulate an RFIF tag in metal and still have it working? Maybe by using the metal as part of the antenna? Low frequency RFID eg 100kHz?

Material - Platinum. Representative enclosure 40mm x 40mm x 5mm with a wall thickness of 1mm.

Comment: Have a look at this Q and A : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/97814/152903

Comment: does ferrite count as metal?

Comment: There are many RFID frequencies. You will need to find one that 'fits' your enclosure top or bottom, and resonates as a 1/4 wavelength antenna (ideally).

Comment: Also the RFID protocol is bidirectional. The device is 'pinged' with a power pulse train to wake up the RFID chip. In return it modulates the pulses so the tag can be read. The usual range for RFID is 1 meter. I would re-think about what you doing.

Comment: what's the approximate size of the enclosure?  40 feet? 40 millimeters?  active (battery powered) tag or passive?(wave powered)

Comment: @Jasen Size would be approx 40mm x 40mm x 4mm

Comment: Many RFID's operate in HF, VHF and UHF ranges.  Someone suggested 100kHz which is VLF technology (which I ignored in my responses) . You must specify to make your question valid. and 125k, 134k is probably your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

There will be some attenuation from skin effect and Eddy Current losses dependent on c/fd ratio for d=thickness and speed of light c in air. So 100kHz will be attenuate slightly and result in loss of range, how much depends on material and thickness.

**EDIT:**  Skin Depth of Platinum is twice that of Cu. (better due to conductivity)

Skin depth is defined by 1/e or when the signal is 37% of the original.

\$\delta=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi f \mu  \sigma}}\$  for variables frequency, permeability and conductivity

.
[image] courtesy Wiki /Zurek's

Eddy Current Losses are defined by;

\$P =\dfrac{π^2B^2_pd^2f^2}{6kρD} \$
where
P is the power lost per unit mass [W/kg]
B is the peak magnetic field [T]
d is the thickness of the sheet or diameter of  the wire [m]
f is the frequency [Hz]
k is a constant equal to 1 for a thin sheet and 2 for a thin wire
ρ is the resistivity of the material [Ω-m]
D is the density of the material [kg/m³]

Comment: Does a 100kHz near field signal go through a microwave door? (rhetorical)

Comment: no. metal will block the signals. you will need slots over the antenna to allow the signal through.

Comment: and the antenna efficiency of the slot is proportional to the ratio of aperture and wavelength so .. no go.  Try 10GHz

Comment: Standard copper foil -- 35micron, or 1.4 mils thick ---has skin effect of 8.9dB (1 neper) at 4MHz. At 100Khz, the attenuation will be sqrt( 100,000 / 4,000,000) smaller, or well under 1dB.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 most common  RFID tags are near field, not working on wavelength based effects, but simple electromagnetic coupling.

Comment: @Jasen yet with a ground plane surrounding the emitted magnetic burst, the current loop flux will just circulate inside the box.  THey often use Copper shunts to wrap around HDD rotary voice coils to reduce the crosstalk from VCM to magnetic disk. But if it was just a floating wall I agree with skin effect loss and then the H field changes shape only

Comment: so does the braided wire of coaxial cable offer no shielding to low voltage near 0 ohm solenoids with high current? Where is the breakpoint? 100kHz? 10kHz?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Similar to the question as to whether one can wind a solenoid using coax if the shield is grounded, and still get a magnetic field when using AC

Comment: I think Eddy Current Losses have been ignored here. Anyone care to compute Lenz's Law and Dirk what f are you using?

Comment: My 1st design was a 15~21KHz radio that picked up signals half-way around the globe.  These were electric fields in the uV range and used before GPS was invented used for Doppler tracking in the Arctic Beaufort Sea.   I just used a whip antenna. The wind powered Weather station it was connected to, ended up in USSR about 10 yrs later as it was floating on an ice flow moving up to 10miles/day. But If I put my antenna inside the metal roof building, the signal was much lower. So I used the lab near a window....ALSO what metal did you have in mind? SS, Cu, Al, Fe?

Comment: I wonder if Olympic Scoring methods should be used or those who judge can be explicit as [-1] could represent ignorance or a fundamental flaw in anyone.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 are you seriously suggesting that a mile long slot would be needed for 125Khz tags ?  A slot thousands of times larger than the antenna,

Comment: obviously not... but the question originally did not specify f